# Mapping ranges of integers to dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, integer, range

If I have a dataframe with postal codes I want to create a new column labeled "Region" which takes several ranges of postal codes and assigns them to a particular region. ex.

if the postal code is from 1000--1209 then the region should be 'NSW'

```
myregion={ 1000:'NSW', 1001:'NSW'}
```

```
Postal Code
1000
1001
...
1209
2000
2001
299
```

The desired dataframe would be :

```
Postal Code  Region
1000         NSW
1001         NSW
...
1209         NSW
2000
2001
299
```

How would I do this in python? what would be the correct syntax? Thanks so much!

Comment: Suggestion you can store `NSW: range(1000,1210)`

Comment: I tried this, it did not work for ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on

> if the postal code is from 1000--1209 then the region should be 'NSW'

I came up with this:

```
def assign_region(x):
    myregion = { 'NSW': range(1000, 1210)
                 # etc
               }
    for region, r in myregion.items():
        if x in r:
            return region


df['Region'] = df['Postal Code'].apply(assign_region)
```

Comment: Just remember that `range(x,y)` contains numbers from x to **y-1**, and enter your data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
def get_region(postal_code):

    if postal_code >= 1000 and postal_code <= 1209:
        return 'NSW'

    ...other cases...

df['Region'] = df['Postal Code'].apply(lambda x: get_region(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First option is to use a postal code api... use the one you like the best.
Second option is manually creating a function, that maps the number to string and then using .map on the dataframe to create new Series in it.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` allows a vectorized operation:

```
df['Region'] = np.where((df['Postal Code']>=1000)&(df['Postal Code']<=1209), 'NSW', '')
```